# get the value from variable in if else statement in php

Tags: php

I want to  get the value from variable in if  else statement here and store the value in **$mydata variable**.
When I try to print it or use it in another place nothing appear, it look like nothing stored in there and I want to use it in another php block in the same file.
I also tried to make it in function and use it direct in the block I want but the same.

**first block that have the value I need to:**

```
<?php
    $mydata; //here when I give it a value directly it work so good but I don't need it like that

         if($t1) { 
                        //statement 
                         if(//check statement ){
    
                             $mydata = 'user1';
        
                         }else
                             // echo message ;
                       }
                       else if($t2){ 
                            //statement 
        
                            if(//check statement ){
        
        
                              $mydata = 'user2';
        
                          }
                          } else
                            // echo message ;
                     }
?>
```

Second php block :

```
if(// check statement ) {
         echo ' <form  action="file2.php" method="post">
             // input fields 
          <input type="hidden" name="table" value='.$mydata.'>
         <input  name="login" type="submit" value="submit"> ';
)
```

Comment: Could it be that `$mydata` does not get assigned a value in your code? Because if your first statement is not `true` you only `echo` a message, not reassign your variable.

Comment: If you set `$mydata` directly in the first block and you see it show up in second block, then it sounds like your `if..else if` statements are not evaluating true.

Comment: I just check where the id belong to which table in database user1 table or user2

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you have written your if...else statement, I have sanitized it for you so that your **$mydata** variable is now visible and accessible as expected.

$t1 to $t4 are the various test conditions you will like to check your decisions against.

```
<?php
$t1 = 1;
$t2 = 1;
$t3 = 1;
$t4 = 1;

if ($t1) {
    //statement
    if ($t3) {

        $mydata = 'user1';

    } else {
        // echo message ;
    }
} else if ($t2) {
    //statement

    if ($t4) {

        $mydata = 'user2';

    }
} else {
    // echo message ;
}

echo $mydata;

if ($t4) {
    echo ' <form  action="file2.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="table" value=' . $mydata . '>
         <input  name="login" type="submit" value="submit">
         </form>';
}
;
?>
```